# Get row count from a certain table in multiple databases

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to know the row count of a certain table that exists (or don't) in multiple bases.

Here's what i came with:

```
DECLARE @NomeBase as char(60)
declare @base as char(100)
declare @select as char(1000)

DECLARE CBases CURSOR FOR  select databasename from sig_orgao_web
 --gets all my databases
OPEN CBases
FETCH NEXT FROM CBases INTO  @NomeBase 

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
  BEGIN           
    set @base =rtrim(@NomeBase) + '.dbo.sia_pais' -- database.dbo.table format
    select @base
    set @select = 'SELECT cast(  count(*) as char(70)) from ' + @base 
    exec (@select)

    FETCH NEXT FROM CBases INTO  @NomeBase
  END
CLOSE CBases
DEALLOCATE CBases
```

I know that tablenames have to be static, so i'm creating the select statements dinamically. 
The results are like this:

```
SIIG_DAT_DESENV.dbo.sia_pais    
13
SIIG_DAT_HOMOLOGACAO.dbo.sia_pais
13
```

And it goes on.

The thing is, if the table doesn't exist in my database or if the user which is running this script on management studio doesn't have access to a certain database, an error will be thrown.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Whats the error you are getting?

Comment: @Hiten004 I'm guessing "Invalid object name..." ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check for the existence of the object in each iteration:

```
set @select = 'IF Object_ID(''' + @base + ''') IS NOT NULL BEGIN SELECT cast(  count(*) as char(70)) from ' + @base + ' END'
```

If you want to check *every* database then you should try this nifty one-liner:

```
EXEC sp_msForEachDB 'IF Object_ID(''[?].dbo.sia_pais'') IS NOT NULL BEGIN SELECT Count(*) FROM [?].dbo.sia_pais END';
```

Comment: That sp works great! Just one thing: how can i print the the database name as well?

Comment: @JoaoVictor the `?` is used as a place holder for the database name... `EXEC sp_msForEachDB 'SELECT ''?'' As dbname'`